# Boost Asio accessing asio::ip::address underlying data and byte ordering

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, asyncsocket

My goal is to create a unique ID for all IP address - port pair. The UID must be same across systems (no conflict for different endian systems). Size of IPV4 UID is 6 bytes and for ipv6 is 18 bytes.

```
uint8_t sourcePair[18];     /*ipv4=(4+2) bytes or ipv6=(16+2) bytes*/
```

I have two functions that will take the remote endpoint of a socket and get the desired UID. The design is as follows.

```
void CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV4(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& remoteEp, unsigned short portNum, unsigned char(&binSourcePair)[18])
{
    auto addressClass = remoteEp.address().to_v4();
    auto ipBin = addressClass.to_uint();
    memcpy(&binSourcePair[0], &ipBin, 4);
    memcpy(&binSourcePair[4], &portNum, 2);
}

void CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV6(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& remoteEp, unsigned short portNum, unsigned char(&binSourcePair)[18])
{
    auto addressClass = remoteEp.address().to_v6();
    auto ipBin = addressClass.to_bytes();
    memcpy(&binSourcePair[0], &ipBin[0], 16);
    memcpy(&binSourcePair[16], &portNum, 2);
}
```

This is how these functions are called

```
remoteEp = socketPtr->remote_endpoint();
if (remoteEp.address().is_v4())
    CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV4(remoteEp, remoteEp.port(), sourcePair);
else
    CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV6(remoteEp, remoteEp.port(), sourcePair);
```

Here the problem is the only way to access the IPv6 underlying data is using to_byte() which will give the data in network byte order. Also, I am doing a memcopy in unsigned short which is multibyte in length. Does this work? Is it a safe way? Is their any workarounds?

Comment: The only problems jumping to mind are that the port number is in native byte order, and you don't show accounting for garbage that could be at the end of the IPv4 binary buffer.

Comment: @ZuodianHu Thank you for the comment, some say "memcpy() does not modify byte order". If it's true I am only concerned about  IPv6 in network byte order. The SourcePair only uses [0-5] in case of IPv4 (It's hardcoded).

Answer (score 0):

```
void CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV4(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& remoteEp, unsigned short portNum, uint8_t(&sourcePair)[18])
{
    auto addressClass = remoteEp.address().to_v4();
    auto ipBin = addressClass.to_bytes();
    memcpy(&sourcePair[0], &ipBin[0], 4);

    #ifdef BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE
    byteSwap(portNum);
    #endif
    memcpy(&sourcePair[4], &portNum, 2);
}

void CmdInterpreter::makeSourcePairV6(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& remoteEp, unsigned short portNum, uint8_t(&sourcePair)[18])
{
    auto addressClass = remoteEp.address().to_v6();
    auto ipBin = addressClass.to_bytes();
    memcpy(&sourcePair[0], &ipBin[0], 16);
    #ifdef BOOST_ENDIAN_LITTLE_BYTE
    byteSwap(portNum);
    #endif
    memcpy(&sourcePair[16], &portNum, 2);
}
```

For both IPv4 and IPv6 address, use to_byte() function to get the remote endpoint address in big-endian format. For little-endian host, the port number will make endianness problem which can be fixed by swapping the bytes. To encode it to base 64 I used cppcodec library.

```
UID = cppcodec::base64_rfc4648::encode(sourcePair, 6);
UID = cppcodec::base64_rfc4648::encode(sourcePair, 18);
```

The template function used to swap the port number is:

```
template <typename T>
void byteSwap(T& portNumber)
{
    char* startIndex = static_cast<char*>((void*)&portNumber);
    char* endIndex = startIndex + sizeof(T);
    std::reverse(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```